# I am having a requirement in Session Management OAM

Tags: java, session

I am having a requirement in Session Management.

I am having custom login page in `.net`. After successful authentication user will be validated for OTP which is a JSP page whether user is single factor or 2 factor. Which is protected by OAM.

Before validating OTP for user I need to write a code to verify:

1. If user session already exists or not?
2. a) If session exists, user should get a page with options of, to continue with old session or new session.

   I.    If user clicks on old session, then user will be logged out from current session and can continue old session.

   II.    If user clicks on new session, then user old session will be terminated and continues with new session.

   b)    If user session not exists, then user will log into App after validating otp.

Can some one please give me an idea on how to write code for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [**HttpSession**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) for this.

1. `If user session already exists or not?`

   Check that session is null or not.

   [request.getSession()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29) != null
2. `If user clicks on old session, then user will be logged out from current session and can continue old session.`

   Use:

   [request.getSession(false)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29);

3)   `If user clicks on new session, then user old session will be terminated and continues with new session.`

Use:

[session.invalidate();](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate%28%29)

and

[request.getSession()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29);

Comment: How can i intercept a page in middle to show an option for user to continue old session or new session.

Comment: Where do i need to add code? on top of JSP code or do i need to create new class and import it in JSP.

Comment: You need to check the session before loading the jsp inside Servlet.

Comment: Sorry, Iam new to J2EE. Can you please tell me the code how i can impement.

Comment: This link contains a video tutorial for session management http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=32UGARg8AzU

Comment: Sorry i can't access Youtube at this moment. If you don't mind can you please tell me the code how to design. Iam having Java class to generate OTP and otp jsp page. Let me know where to add the code

Comment: Iam develpoing a jsp page. Checking the reffere url if it contains otp.jsp then check for valid session. If valid session exists then show message : you have active session. buttons are :new session and old session. How to check for perticular user there is valid session or not?

Comment: To check that session is valid or not you should set some user details in the session at the time of authentication(login). So that you can validate the session based on user details are present in the session or not.

Comment: Hi Ankur, iam developing page with 2 buttons as old session and new session. If user clicks on old session then the current session should be terminated. If user clicks on new session then old existing session should terminate and continue to validate OTP page. How can i write the buttons.